# Dimension of Abelian Lie Algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

I've tried to answer this question, but I need some help.

What is the possible dimension of irreducible representations of Abelian Lie Algebras? I think it is always one, but I am not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to formulate what a representations of an Abelian Lie Algebra is precisely. And what it maens for it to be irreducible.